# Find number of multiplication operations in sincnet

Tags: conv-neural-network

From the implementation of [sincnet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00158) - there are 3 matmul functions (calculate low band, high band and conv1D)

For out_channel = 80, Filter_len=401, Input length = 24567 for 1.5s audio

Low & high band = 2*80*401 ops (negligible)
Conv1D = out_channel*filter_len*input_size = 788M or 525MOps/s

But is this calculation correct? It seems too high when sincnet was supposed to be more optimized.

Raw [implementation](https://gist.github.com/hbredin/c3bfa80f8f71181c2d499167d297f181)